# What is this mean?

Tags: muslim-practices

[image: i am muslim .i got this paper inside my friends cupboard.can youplease help me in knowing the meaning.i will be greatful.it was wrapped in a red color cloth]
Please tell the meaning of the same.what could be the harm it can cause?
Do i need to worry?

Comment: I can't see how this is related to Islam at all.

Answer (score 2):

It has Urdu numerals written on it, which are similar to Arabic numerals.

[image]

Translated, it would read:

> 786
>   ? 6 8 0 8 3 6 9
>   8 6 7 0 7 5 8 1
>   7 1 8 5 7 8 7 4
>   7 9 1 3 7 6 7 4

This is [Gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) or [Abjad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad_numerals), which is an esoteric practice (with no proven Islamic basis) of assigning numerical values to letters and summing them to get a numeric value of a sentence.

The first line: 786 is the value of *Bismillah* (refer to [What does 786 mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/799/what-does-786-mean/))

I have no idea what the rest of the values stand for.